# Django urlpatterns, instances?

Tags: django

From the official docs:

> urlpatterns should be a list of url() instances.

For example:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^index/$', index_view, name='main-view'),
    url(r'^weblog/', include('blog.urls')),
    ...
]
```

Here is where I get confused, url() is not just a function ? Why they use OO terminology or thats valid or I missing something?

Comment: Not sure what your question is here. What do you mean by OO terminology ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just loose phrasing. `url()` is a function that returns a RegexULRPattern instance; but you'd never instantiate that class directly yourself, `url()` is the interface to it.